# Impossible provisioning vagrant with packer

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I would like to add package (eg : apache2) in a packer script for create a Vagrant (virtualbox-iso) that contain apache2 server installed.

For that I use this example project which run correctly (but without my package apache2) : [Packer project for Vagrant Ubuntu](https://github.com/jose-lpa/packer-ubuntu_14.04)

I just add 2 command in base.sh script

- `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`
- `apt-get -y install apache2`

The build packer run correctly and the Vagrant run correctly also but when a enter the vagrant with ssh I never find anyway a apache2 installation

However the build log tell me that apache2 package is installed correctly.
For that the team packer doesn't want to help me because she think that is a Vagrant problem, not a Packer

log

```
    2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: The following extra packages will be installed:
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: apache2-bin apache2-data libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: libaprutil1-ldap ssl-cert
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Suggested packages:
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: www-browser apache2-doc apache2-suexec-pristine apache2-suexec-custom
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: apache2-utils openssl-blacklist
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: The following NEW packages will be installed:
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: apache2 apache2-bin apache2-data libapr1 libaprutil1 libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: libaprutil1-ldap ssl-cert
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: 0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 69 not upgraded.
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Need to get 1,285 kB of archives.
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: After this operation, 5,348 kB of additional disk space will be used.
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libapr1 amd64 1.5.0-1 [85.1 kB]
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaprutil1 amd64 1.5.3-1 [76.4 kB]
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3 amd64 1.5.3-1 [10.5 kB]
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main libaprutil1-ldap amd64 1.5.3-1 [8,634 B]
2016/01/09 17:43:07 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apache2-bin amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8 [840 kB]
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apache2-data all 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8 [160 kB]
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main apache2 amd64 2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8 [87.6 kB]
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main ssl-cert all 1.0.33 [16.6 kB]
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preconfiguring packages ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Fetched 1,285 kB in 1s (859 kB/s)
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package libapr1:amd64.
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: (Reading database ... 61917 files and directories currently installed.)
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../libapr1_1.5.0-1_amd64.deb ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking libapr1:amd64 (1.5.0-1) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1:amd64.
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking libaprutil1:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64.
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package libaprutil1-ldap:amd64.
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../libaprutil1-ldap_1.5.3-1_amd64.deb ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package apache2-bin.
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../apache2-bin_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb ...
2016/01/09 17:43:08 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking apache2-bin (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package apache2-data.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../apache2-data_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8_all.deb ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking apache2-data (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package apache2.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../apache2_2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8_amd64.deb ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Selecting previously unselected package ssl-cert.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Preparing to unpack .../ssl-cert_1.0.33_all.deb ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Unpacking ssl-cert (1.0.33) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for man-db (2.6.7.1-1ubuntu1) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up libapr1:amd64 (1.5.0-1) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up libaprutil1:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up libaprutil1-dbd-sqlite3:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up libaprutil1-ldap:amd64 (1.5.3-1) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up apache2-bin (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up apache2-data (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up apache2 (2.4.7-1ubuntu4.8) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module mpm_event.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module authz_core.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module authz_host.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module authn_core.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module auth_basic.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module access_compat.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module authn_file.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module authz_user.
2016/01/09 17:43:09 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module alias.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module dir.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module autoindex.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module env.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module mime.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module negotiation.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module setenvif.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module filter.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module deflate.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling module status.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling conf charset.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling conf localized-error-pages.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling conf other-vhosts-access-log.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling conf security.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling conf serve-cgi-bin.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Enabling site 000-default.
2016/01/09 17:43:10 ui:     virtualbox-iso: * Starting web server apache2
2016/01/09 17:43:11 ui:     virtualbox-iso: *
2016/01/09 17:43:11 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Setting up ssl-cert (1.0.33) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:11 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-0ubuntu6.6) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:11 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-16) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:11 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Processing triggers for ufw (0.34~rc-0ubuntu2) ...
2016/01/09 17:43:12 ui:     virtualbox-iso: [sudo] password for vagrant: Generating grub configuration file ...
2016/01/09 17:43:12 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.19.0-25-generic
2016/01/09 17:43:12 ui:     virtualbox-iso: Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.19.0-25-generic
2016/01/09 17:43:13 packer-builder-virtualbox-iso.exe: 2016/01/09 17:43:13 remote command exited with '0': echo 'vagrant'|sudo -S sh '/tmp/script_7943.sh'
2016/01/09 17:43:13 packer-builder-virtualbox-iso.exe: 2016/01/09 17:43:13 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2016/01/09 17:43:13 [INFO] RPC client: Communicator ended with: 0
2016/01/09 17:43:13 [INFO] RPC endpoint: Communicator ended with: 0
2016/01/09 17:43:13 [INFO] 12338 bytes written for 'stdout'
2016/01/09 17:43:13 [INFO] 179 bytes written for 'stderr'
2016/01/09 17:43:13 ui:     virtualbox-iso: done
```

What process of Vagrant can cause this strange behaviour ? (cache system, virtualbox cache....)

I try

- delete .builds directory of project
- delete image vm in virtualbox
- delete packer_cache directory in project
- create my own script that added in template
- start from scratch a new packer project with same result

***It seems to be a very very strange problem that not concern just a script but also the mechanism of vagrant and virtualbox run.***

**Why my package installed never find in my vagrant ?**

config

- OS Host : windows 7 pro
- OS Guest : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
- VM technology : VirtualBox 5.0.10
- VM technology : Vagrant 1.7.4
- VM tools builder : Packer 0.8.6

Comment: Did you create a Vagrant VM using the box built by the original Packer run before you edited `base.sh`?

Comment: There is not original packer for build Vagrant. to this end a use a packer project.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following your response. You said the example project ran correctly. The example project includes a Packer build followed by `vagrant up` using the box from that build. Did you run `vagrant up` after building the example box file? Or did you edit `base.sh`, run Packer again, and then run `vagrant up` for the first time?

Comment: I edit base.sh for add apache2 and run packer which run and build correctly vagrant for the rest of package.the problem is log packer build with apache and in vagrant there is no apache2. I'm use Vagrantfile with the box generated by packer in builds directory project.

Comment: Ok, so just to be completely clear... the very first time you ran Vagrant was after you edited `base.sh` and ran Packer? This is a very important detail.

Comment: get packer project -> edit base.sh -> run build packer -> vagrant up (my log packer build write that apache2 package was installed)

Answer (score 1):

So here are the key details that we know. We can see in the output from your Packer build that Apache is clearly being installed. Thus the resulting box file includes an Apache installation and using it to create a Vagrant VM should result in that VM having Apache installed. However, in your case the Vagrant VM does **not** have Apache installed.

Using the process of elimination, here is what I think happened. You must have already added a Vagrant box with the same name prior to the Vagrant run using the box file from Packer. When you do a `vagrant up`, Vagrant will look at the name of the box in the Vagrantfile (`config.vm.box` in this case), check to see if it already has a box by that name, and use it if it exists. Otherwise Vagrant will use the box URL (`config.vm.box_url` here) to find the new box and then add it with the name provided.

You know that your box file from Packer has Apache installed. You just need to make sure that Vagrant imports that box instead of using one by the same name that it already has. In order to do that, you need to remove it prior to running Vagrant...

```
vagrant box remove ubuntu-14.04-amd64
vagrant up
```

Then your Vagrant VM will use the box created by Packer which already has Apache installed.